# Failed to set user properties (id) to the serializeUser even that the user is not empty is the passport,

Tags: node.js, serialization, oauth-2.0, passport.js, session-cookies

in google oauth2 with nodejs project using sequelize, i find an issue that take me a lot time without solution, even that i write it in chatgpt4 but there's no a solution,
i debug me code and i find the problem is while the serializing, the the cause is the done that i want to give the user.id parameter is undefiend,
"Error when trying to serialize user: ReferenceError: profile is not defined "

`passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) { console.log('serializeUser: ' + user._id) done(null, user._id); });`

i try to update the version of passport then i was have a doubt in the http, i thought that the authentication with oauth2 should be with Https, so i make a certification with ssl, but still the same issue,

this passport.js --->

```
var FacebookStrategy = require('passport-facebook').Strategy;
var GoogleStrategy = require('passport-google-oauth20').Strategy;
const sequelize = require('../config/db');
var TwiterStrategy = require('passport-twitter').Strategy;
var User = require('../model/User');
var UserRepository = require('../repository/user_repository');

var configAuth = require('../config/auth');

  // Put this somewhere in your code where it gets executed before the Google strategy
User.sync({ force: true }) // Don't force sync, as it drops the table if it already exists
.then(() => console.log('Users table created successfully'))
.catch(err => console.error('Could not create Users table', err));
module.exports = function(passport){

passport.use(new GoogleStrategy({
  clientID: configAuth.googleAuth.clientID,
  clientSecret: configAuth.googleAuth.clientSecret,
  callbackURL: configAuth.googleAuth.callbackURL
}, function (token, refreshToken, profile, done) {
  console.log('profile pic ' + profile.photos[0].value);
  User.findOrCreate({
    where: { id: profile.id.toString() },
    defaults: {
      api_type: 'GOOGLE',
      token: token,
      email: profile.emails[0].value,
      name: profile.displayName
    }
  }).then(([user, created]) => {
   

    if (created) {
      profile = user
      console.log('Created new user: ' + user.name);
          // Now profile should be a copy of the user, and you can access its properties
          console.log("this is id in profile  : ",profile.id); // Outputs "116413686074351163016"
          console.log("this is api_type in profile  : ",profile.api_type); // 
          console.log("this is token in profile  : ",profile.token); // 
          console.log("this is email in profile  : ",profile.email); // 
          console.log("this is name in profile  : ",profile.name); // Outputs "116413686074351163016"
    } else {
      console.log('Found existing user: ' + user.name);
    }
    console.log("this is profile: ", user.profile); // Logging the user object
    console.log("this is user in passport  : ", user.dataValues); // Logging the Sequelize user instance
    done(null, user.dataValues); // Passing the user dataValues object to serializeUser
  }).catch((err) => {
    done(err);
  });
}));

passport.serializeUser((user, done) => {
  console.log("this is user in serializeUser: ", JSON.stringify(user)); // Logging the user object
  //console.log("this is profile: ", profile); // Logging the user object
  try {
    console.log("this is user in serializeUser before serialize: ", JSON.stringify(user)); // Logging the user object
    //done(null, user.dataValues); // Assuming 'id' is the primary key in your user model
    console.log('serializeUser id user.id: ' + user._id);
    console.log('serializeUser id profile.id: ' + profile._id);
    done(null, user.id); // Assuming 'id' is the primary key in your user model
    console.log("this is user in serializeUser after serialize: ", JSON.stringify(user)); // Logging the user object
  } catch(err) {
    done(err);
    console.error('Error when trying to serialize user:', err);
  }
});

passport.deserializeUser(function(id, done) {
  User.findByPk(id)
    .then(user => {
      done(null, user);
    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.error('Error when trying to deserialize user:', err);
      done(err);
    });
});

}
```

and this app.js --->

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var favicon = require('serve-favicon');
var logger = require('morgan');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
const cookieSession = require('cookie-session');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var passport = require('passport');
var flash = require('connect-flash');
var session = require('express-session')
var helmet = require('helmet');
var cors = require('cors');
var rateLimit = require('express-rate-limit');
var compression = require('compression');
var app = express();


const https = require('https');
const fs = require('fs');

const privateKey = fs.readFileSync('./ssl/privateKey.key', 'utf8');
const certificate = fs.readFileSync('./ssl/certificate.crt', 'utf8');

const credentials = { key: privateKey, cert: certificate };
//app.use(session({ secret: 'flymetothemoon', resave: true, saveUninitialized: true }));
app.use(cookieSession({ secret: 'flymetothemoon!', cookie: { maxAge: new Date(Date.now() +     3600000), }}));
app.use(flash()); // Initialize connect-flash before passport middleware
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'jade');

app.use(helmet());
app.use(cors());

app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));

// ... (other middleware)
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

console.log("passport : "+ passport)

// ... (rest of the middleware)

// Rate limiting
const limiter = rateLimit({
  windowMs: 15 * 60 * 1000, // 15 minutes
  max: 100 // limit each IP to 100 requests per windowMs
});
app.use(limiter);

require('./app/config/passport')(passport);
require('./routes/routes')(app, passport);


app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  // Set the authenticated user in the
  // template locals
  if (req.user) {
   res.locals.user = req.user.profile;
  }
  next();
 });

// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  var err = new Error('Not Found');
  err.status = 404;
  next(err);
});

//catch 500 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  console.error('Unhandled error:', err);
  res.status(500).send('Something broke!');
});

/*
// error handlers
// app.js or index.js (your main application file)
const User = require('./app/model/User');

async function syncDatabase() {
  try {
    await User.sync();
    console.log('User table synchronized successfully.');
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error synchronizing User table:', error);
  }
}

// Call the syncDatabase function to create the User table
syncDatabase();
*/
// development error handler
// will print stacktrace
if (app.get('env') === 'development') {
  app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
    res.status(err.status || 500);
    res.render('error', {
      message: err.message,
      error: err
    });
  });
}
app.get('/auth/google',
  passport.authenticate('google', { scope: ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login', 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.profile.emails.read'] }));

// production error handler
// no stacktraces leaked to user
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.render('error', {
    message: err.message,
    error: {}
  });
});
const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;
const httpsServer = https.createServer(credentials, app);
httpsServer.listen(port, function() {
    console.log(`HTTPS Server running on port ${port}`);
});

module.exports = app;
```

model/User.js --->

```
/*
var User = function(id, apiType, token, email, name){
  this.id = id;
  this.apiType = apiType;
  this.token = token;
  this.email = email;
  this.name = name;
}

module.exports = User;
*/
// models/User.js
const { DataTypes } = require('sequelize');
const sequelize = require('../config/db');

const User = sequelize.define('User', {
  id: {
    type: DataTypes.STRING,
    primaryKey: true
  //,autoIncrement: true,
  },
  api_type: {
    type: DataTypes.STRING
    ,allowNull: false,
  },
  token: {
    type: DataTypes.STRING
    ,allowNull: false,
  },
  email: {
    type: DataTypes.STRING
    ,allowNull: false,
  },
  name: {
    type: DataTypes.STRING
    ,allowNull: false,
  },
});

module.exports = User;
```

and this what terminal show!

```
`[nodemon] restarting due to changes...
[nodemon] starting `node ./bin/www`
passport : [object Object]
HTTPS Server running on port 3000
Executing (default): DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "Users" CASCADE;
Executing (default): CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "Users" ("id" VARCHAR(255) , "api_type" VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, "token" VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, "email" VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, "name" VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, "createdAt" TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE NOT NULL, "updatedAt" TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY ("id"));
Executing (default): SELECT i.relname AS name, ix.indisprimary AS primary, ix.indisunique AS unique, ix.indkey AS indkey, array_agg(a.attnum) as column_indexes, array_agg(a.attname) AS column_names, pg_get_indexdef(ix.indexrelid) AS definition FROM pg_class t, pg_class i, pg_index ix, pg_attribute a WHERE t.oid = ix.indrelid AND i.oid = ix.indexrelid AND a.attrelid = t.oid AND t.relkind = 'r' and t.relname = 'Users' GROUP BY i.relname, ix.indexrelid, ix.indisprimary, ix.indisunique, ix.indkey ORDER BY i.relname;
Users table created successfully
GET /auth/google 302 3.961 ms - 0
profile pic https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/a/AAcHTtcBR2b7oWLxbiOgOpdAF6pQ0oyimAw4i6urIt9MwxED=s96-c
Executing (c7b7bfb6-52e3-4cd4-8a79-ceaff33b3781): START TRANSACTION;
Executing (c7b7bfb6-52e3-4cd4-8a79-ceaff33b3781): SELECT "id", "api_type", "token", "email", "name", "createdAt", "updatedAt" FROM "Users" AS "User" WHERE "User"."id" = '116413686074351163016';
Executing (c7b7bfb6-52e3-4cd4-8a79-ceaff33b3781): CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION pg_temp.testfunc(OUT response "Users", OUT sequelize_caught_exception text) RETURNS RECORD AS $func_4db8565db1704fba9e3b8365a1df9fbc$ BEGIN INSERT INTO "Users" ("id","api_type","token","email","name","createdAt","updatedAt") VALUES ('116413686074351163016','GOOGLE','ya29.a0AbVbY6MVvkDWotTFxQGs8LY-MmJG1jI-XupqeE_9LvflNaWVF__xYuKmgwv7LJnnOJ49VHmRBkqENm7rrVF81s37QJU_lKePjdS5hThEikUK70OWPxq8qMsT9uE3EceJlvHUTSYLHC8PWq5Ee3SYNzq2EHWhaCgYKAXgSARISFQFWKvPlDfm4gBrXbBJY7CSZ60qY5Q0163','achref.hjaiej@esprit.tn','Achref Hjaiej','2023-07-31 12:59:24.178 +00:00','2023-07-31 12:59:24.178 +00:00') RETURNING * INTO response; EXCEPTION WHEN unique_violation THEN GET STACKED DIAGNOSTICS sequelize_caught_exception = PG_EXCEPTION_DETAIL; END $func_4db8565db1704fba9e3b8365a1df9fbc$ LANGUAGE plpgsql; SELECT (testfunc.response)."id", (testfunc.response)."api_type", (testfunc.response)."token", (testfunc.response)."email", (testfunc.response)."name", (testfunc.response)."createdAt", (testfunc.response)."updatedAt", testfunc.sequelize_caught_exception FROM pg_temp.testfunc(); DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS pg_temp.testfunc();
Executing (c7b7bfb6-52e3-4cd4-8a79-ceaff33b3781): COMMIT;
Created new user: Achref Hjaiej
this is id in profile  :  116413686074351163016
this is api_type in profile  :  GOOGLE
this is token in profile  :  ya29.a0AbVbY6MVvkDWotTFxQGs8LY-MmJG1jI-XupqeE_9LvflNaWVF__xYuKmgwv7LJnnOJ49VHmRBkqENm7rrVF81s37QJU_lKePjdS5hThEikUK70OWPxq8qMsT9uE3EceJlvHUTSYLHC8PWq5Ee3SYNzq2EHWhaCgYKAXgSARISFQFWKvPlDfm4gBrXbBJY7CSZ60qY5Q0163
this is email in profile  :  achref.hjaiej@esprit.tn
this is name in profile  :  Achref Hjaiej
this is profile:  undefined
this is user in passport  :  {
  api_type: 'GOOGLE',
  token: 'ya29.a0AbVbY6MVvkDWotTFxQGs8LY-MmJG1jI-XupqeE_9LvflNaWVF__xYuKmgwv7LJnnOJ49VHmRBkqENm7rrVF81s37QJU_lKePjdS5hThEikUK70OWPxq8qMsT9uE3EceJlvHUTSYLHC8PWq5Ee3SYNzq2EHWhaCgYKAXgSARISFQFWKvPlDfm4gBrXbBJY7CSZ60qY5Q0163',  email: 'achref.hjaiej@esprit.tn',
  name: 'Achref Hjaiej',
  id: '116413686074351163016',
  updatedAt: 2023-07-31T12:59:24.178Z,
  createdAt: 2023-07-31T12:59:24.178Z
}
this is user in serializeUser:  {"api_type":"GOOGLE","token":"ya29.a0AbVbY6MVvkDWotTFxQGs8LY-MmJG1jI-XupqeE_9LvflNaWVF__xYuKmgwv7LJnnOJ49VHmRBkqENm7rrVF81s37QJU_lKePjdS5hThEikUK70OWPxq8qMsT9uE3EceJlvHUTSYLHC8PWq5Ee3SYNzq2EHWhaCgYKAXgSARISFQFWKvPlDfm4gBrXbBJY7CSZ60qY5Q0163","email":"achref.hjaiej@esprit.tn","name":"Achref Hjaiej","id":"116413686074351163016","updatedAt":"2023-07-31T12:59:24.178Z","createdAt":"2023-07-31T12:59:24.178Z"}      
this is user in serializeUser before serialize:  {"api_type":"GOOGLE","token":"ya29.a0AbVbY6MVvkDWotTFxQGs8LY-MmJG1jI-XupqeE_9LvflNaWVF__xYuKmgwv7LJnnOJ49VHmRBkqENm7rrVF81s37QJU_lKePjdS5hThEikUK70OWPxq8qMsT9uE3EceJlvHUTSYLHC8PWq5Ee3SYNzq2EHWhaCgYKAXgSARISFQFWKvPlDfm4gBrXbBJY7CSZ60qY5Q0163","email":"achref.hjaiej@esprit.tn","name":"Achref Hjaiej","id":"116413686074351163016","updatedAt":"2023-07-31T12:59:24.178Z","createdAt":"2023-07-31T12:59:24.178Z"}
serializeUser id user.id: undefined
Unhandled error: ReferenceError: profile is not defined
    at C:\Users\ACHRAF\Downloads\nodejs-social-auth-master\nodejs-social-auth-master\app\config\passport.js:60:51
    at pass (C:\Users\ACHRAF\Downloads\nodejs-social-auth-master\nodejs-social-auth-master\node_modules\passport\lib\authenticator.js:294:9)
    at Authenticator.serializeUser (C:\Users\ACHRAF\Downloads\nodejs-social-auth-master\nodejs-social-auth-master\node_modules\passport\lib\authenticator.js:299:5)
    at SessionManager.logIn (C:\Users\ACHRAF\Downloads\nodejs-social-auth-master\nodejs-social-auth-master\node_modules\passport\lib\sessionmanager.js:14:8)
    at IncomingMessage.req.login.req.logIn (C:\Users\ACHRAF\Downloads\nodejs-social-auth-master\nodejs-social-auth-master\node_modules\passport\lib\http\request.js:50:33)
    at Strategy.strategy.success (C:\Users\ACHRAF\Downloads\nodejs-social-auth-master\nodejs-social-auth-master\node_modules\passport\lib\middleware\authenticate.js:253:13)
    at verified (C:\Users\ACHRAF\Downloads\nodejs-social-auth-master\nodejs-social-auth-master\node_modules\passport-oauth2\lib\strategy.js:189:20)
    at C:\Users\ACHRAF\Downloads\nodejs-social-auth-master\nodejs-social-auth-master\app\config\passport.js:47:5
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
Error when trying to serialize user: ReferenceError: profile is not defined
    at C:\Users\ACHRAF\Downloads\nodejs-social-auth-master\nodejs-social-auth-master\app\config\passport.js:60:51
    at pass (C:\Users\ACHRAF\Downloads\nodejs-social-auth-master\nodejs-social-auth-master\node_modules\passport\lib\authenticator.js:294:9)
    at Authenticator.serializeUser (C:\Users\ACHRAF\Downloads\nodejs-social-auth-master\nodejs-social-auth-master\node_modules\passport\lib\authenticator.js:299:5)
    at SessionManager.logIn (C:\Users\ACHRAF\Downloads\nodejs-social-auth-master\nodejs-social-auth-master\node_modules\passport\lib\sessionmanager.js:14:8)
    at IncomingMessage.req.login.req.logIn (C:\Users\ACHRAF\Downloads\nodejs-social-auth-master\nodejs-social-auth-master\node_modules\passport\lib\http\request.js:50:33)
    at Strategy.strategy.success (C:\Users\ACHRAF\Downloads\nodejs-social-auth-master\nodejs-social-auth-master\node_modules\passport\lib\middleware\authenticate.js:253:13)
    at verified (C:\Users\ACHRAF\Downloads\nodejs-social-auth-master\nodejs-social-auth-master\node_modules\passport-oauth2\lib\strategy.js:189:20)
    at C:\Users\ACHRAF\Downloads\nodejs-social-auth-master\nodejs-social-auth-master\app\config\passport.js:47:5
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
GET /auth/google/callback?code=4%2F0AZEOvhWB2biBBiSYG-x3P9BETldbNtNuBezBnXGPRmpANIfUEs2QZXmcIqUokxMb4GlbpQ&scope=email+profile+https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fuserinfo.profile+https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fuserinfo.email+openid&authuser=0&hd=esprit.tn&prompt=consent 500 1044.811 ms - 16`
```

and thank you for help